# How do I use X instead of wayland on 22.04?

Tags: xorg, 22.04, wayland

I read posts that said you can switch at the login screen. But I have not option to switch there.

Comment: See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406844/ubuntu-22-04-fresh-installation-firefox-will-no-load/1406857#1406857) to an answer to other question here at AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 41):

You can enable the X using the terminal.
Open the terminal and run the command:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

there you will find

```
WaylandEnable=true
```

change it to

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

And restart the system.

Or you can do the same by following the instructions given in this link here under **GNOME**  heading. [Release Notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/24668)

Comment: I actually found "#WaylandEnable=false" and uncommenting it (removing the # to get "WaylandEnable=false") did it

Comment: (not your fault) Great; this just broke my system. Apparently my X is broken so now it just can't boot.

Comment: I chose the recovery boot option from the Grub menu, booted into a terminal, and undid the change.

Comment: Yes, my ubuntu could not boot up, so I also had to recovery login as root and undid the change

Comment: My first reboot, after uncomment #WaylandEnable=false". Ubuntu just halt somewhere in the boot-process (dark screen). Make a hard turn off, and waited five second, and Ubuntu start as normal (with X11). /Cheers

Comment: I confirm this works, first thing I needed to get going was DPMS stanby and barrier and both those things are broken on wayland, why did they switch over without making sure the software was ready !

Answer (score 19):

**Update:** As @DanglingPointer mentioned in comments below, If you have upgraded the Ubuntu from older version you might be able to change it via the cog wheel as per the steps. If that's not the case, please refer to the steps in [Shreedhar Hegde's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1413490/325833)

On the lock screen,

1. Once clicked on the password field or after typing your password, look for the cog wheel on the right bottom corner & click on it
2. Once clicked, you will be presented with two options - Click on the needed mode

   - Ubuntu (Wayland - the default)
   - Ubuntu on XOrg (The second mode - your expected option)
3. Then just sign-in - You would be logged in to the session on the mode selected

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No cog wheel on my right bottom at the signin screen, 22.04

Comment: rearThing, can you share the screenshot of the screen you are referring ?

Comment: @Aravinth I think you can see the cog wheel because you upgraded over several generations.  Those on fresh install don't have that option.  In my generations upgraded instances, I can see Ubuntu, XOrg, Unity, and Kodi options.

Comment: @DanglingPointer - Thanks for that insight, I was unaware of it. In my case i have upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04, Maybe due to to that i have it there

Comment: @rearThing, Did the Shreedhar Hegde's answer helped in your case?