# Scrot not working with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: scrot-command

Okay as far as my searches go, I haven't found this question posed online...   Has anyone else ran into issues with the screenshot program scrot not working correctly with Ubuntu 22.04?

Currently, the program "works" but only screenshots a black screen, with no error output.

I have even tried exporting the display window just in case with the same issue.

export DISPLAY=:0; scrot test.png

Comment: I should also state that a workaround is the program gnome-screenshot but I don't like how this program flashes the screen when getting a screenshot.

Comment: The problem is most likely that `scrot` doesn't work under Wayland, only Xorg. You can try [switching to Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04) and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `scrot` is specific to `Xorg`, and the newer Ubuntu updates use Wayland by default. If you need to use `scrot`, [switch to using Xorg instead of Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04). Otherwise, check out [other screenshot tools](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Screen_capture) to see if any of them work for you.