# How can I change brightness in [0,1]?

Tags: laptop, brightness, 22.04

I use to increase or decrease the brightness of the monitor using `xrandr` command from [this](https://vitux.com/control-screen-brightness-from-ubuntu-terminal/) in Ubuntu [20.04](https://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/). It gives the liberty of giving custom brightness that can vary from 0 to 1 irrespective of the brightness range provided by the system UI.

After upgrading my OS to Ubuntu [22.04](https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/), it no longer seems to be working. Although there are commands to stepdown the brightness

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepDown

(0, 'eDP-1')
```

The zero brightness it is showing is the same as the 0 brightness of the UI, and I cannot decrease it further. I don't have liberty as I did on the previous version.

What can I do to run `xrandr` or its alternatives so I can give a number from the terminal that works?

Comment: are you using Wayland or Xorg? If Wayland, `xrandr` won't work for you. You can switch back to Xorg to use `xrandr`

Comment: @Esther My system is showing Wayland. So, probably 20.04 is using Xorg.

Comment: yes, 20.04 used xorg by default, 22.04 uses Wayland by default. You can switch it using the gear icon in the bottom-right of the login screen (may only appear if you move your mouse there)

Comment: working @Esther Thanks. Please write it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04 used Xorg as a display manager by default, and Ubuntu 22.04 uses Wayland by default. `xrandr` does not work under Wayland, so it will not work by default on Ubuntu 22.04 unless you switch to using Xorg.

This can be done by either:

1. Using the gear icon in the bottom-right of the login screen. It may not appear until you move your mouse close to there.
2. Using the method described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1413490/1083397) to change the config file.