# touchscreen berserk ubuntu 22.04 xinput wayland

Tags: touchscreen, wayland, xinput, mouse-pointer

I am in desperate need of immediate help. I am typing this out on my phone because I can't use my computer.

Some time ago, something went haywire with my touchscreen. Specifically, the mouse pointer / cursor would jump erratically all over the screen, making the computer uncontrollable. I posted - here, actually, I think - and was told about xinput.

I followed the instructions. Every time my computer starts, I put in an xinput command to disable the touchscreen. This stops the erratic cursor and has served me well for years.

Today I got 22.04. When I ran my trusty xinput command, I got an error that I was trying to run an xinput command against wayland.

My first thought was: what the heck is wayland? But the point is, I urgently need to be able to disable my touchscreen again under this new regime. Can you help? Thanks a ton.

Comment: I have seen some very odd screen issues since moving to 22.04 also.  At times my main screen will freeze (won't display the cursor at all) while my 2nd screen shows cursor moving around.  Usually if I wait then finally the main screen will rendering again.  This usually happens after unlocking the computer.  I believe this is gnome / wayland problems -- never had them before in 5 years of running Ubuntu, until 22.04.

Comment: I just switched from wayland to xorg.  
I followed the instructions at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04
This will remove wayland and run xorg.  
Wow, I was not able to run an Android emulator (via AndroidStudio) until I made the change to Xorg.  This fixed it!!

Comment: @raddevus Thank You! I was able to restart - manually, with the button. Clicking on the login window displays the gear icon. Then just click "Ubuntu on Xorg" and my xinput commands work and my computer is sane. Do you want to make your comment a formal answer for the points?