# Teamviewer - Allow Remote Interaction

Tags: remote-desktop, teamviewer

I've defected from Windows to Ubuntu and have always used TV for remote access.

I've installed it on Ubuntu 22.04 and all's good apart from when I try to remote in, on the remote laptop it needs someone to physically click the "allow remote interaction" and "share" buttons on that machine.

How can I do the settings so that no one has to be present ?

Comment: You have to allow "unattended access" in settings, the same as on windows.

Comment: I have and yet it still asks the question and needs physical interaction

Comment: From what I can gather it's something to do with Wayland not allowing incoming connections automatically and always asks for a prompt for interaction and sharing.

Comment: Sorted it !!All works fine now - found a setting to change from Wayland to Xorg, restarted the TV Daemon and bob's yer Uncle !

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable Wayland, then it works.  Follow the steps here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1413490/296502.