# How to switch from Wayland to Xorg in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: xorg

echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE says my Ubuntu 22.04 is using "wayland". I need to switch to xorg server in order to use "SimpleScreenRecorder" (http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder).

There is no gear wheel (settings) on the login page.
Thanks, John.

Comment: It's not on the login (username) page. It's on the password entry page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use X instead of wayland on 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04)

Answer (score 1):

When you sign in click on the desired account then in the bottom left of the password entry page you will find the gear icon click there and select xorg

In case this does not work see this
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/configuring-xorg-as-default-gnome-session

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. THE login page is not the same as MY login page! So I was able to change to xorg but SSR still recorded only audio. As a last effort I decided to re-install SSR. I went to the Ubuntu catalog page and clicked uninstall. Then Searched for it in the catalog and discovered there's a new version. I installed that and now SSR works fine. Thanks again, at least now I can find the gear wheel which is important.