# Change monitors to 4K resolution

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, display-resolution

I have recently switched over from Windows to Ubuntu, my monitors previously were able to work in 4K on Windows; however, since switching over it seems as though the max resolution I am  able to work at is 1920x1080. I have tried a few `xrandr` solutions that I have been able to find online but I am always left with the below error message.

```
xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_30.00" 297.0 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync -vsync
xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND5 "3840x2160_30.00"
xrandr --output XWAYLAND5 --mode "3840x2160_30.00"

X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x1680
  Serial number of failed request:  36
  Current serial number in output stream:  36
```

Does anyone have any potential fixes for this? For reference I have included the monitors and their names from `xrandr --listmonitors` in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can use `xrandr` under Wayland to do what you want, so I think you have to either switch back to `Xorg` or try different methods as per this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/973499/wayland-how-to-set-a-custom-resolution

Comment: Ahh yeah okay that makes sense, just for clarification it would be switching `xrandr` to `xorg` and then that should work under Wayback correct? Alternatively, is there any better methods instead of Wayback that I could use? Might be a dumb question so apologies if it is, not overly across all of this stuff

Comment: When you login to Ubuntu you have the choice to login using Wayland or Xorg by clicking the gear icon. And once you choose it should stick for subsequent logins. At some Ubuntu version Wayland was made the default, personally I still use Xorg as I use some KVM software that does not work under Wayland (`barrier`). I expect in future it will do but I have no problem using Xorg for now. See here for info on switching: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437175/how-to-switch-from-wayland-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-22-04