# Partial sound in media players Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04, vlc

Problem: When watching movie on VLC or other media player, there is only a partial sound - background sounds only, but there is a lack of sound of dialogues. I can't hear conversations. When playing YT or Spotify in the browser (chrome/firefox), the whole sound can be heard very well.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (installed from bootable usb) with 5.15.0-52-generic kernel.

```
SMBIOS 3.3.0 present.
System Information
    Product Name: ROG Zephyrus G14 GA401QC_GA401QC
```

Some settings:
[pavucontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTfTR.png)

```
hwinfo --sound
15: PCI 400.1: 0403 Audio device                                
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: P5_H.9NFLkWZC7B9
  Parent ID: JZZT.e+TNXSUNut3
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.1
  SysFS BusID: 0000:04:00.1
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "ATI Audio device"
  Vendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
  Device: pci 0x1637 
  SubVendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
  SubDevice: pci 0x1637 
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xfc5c8000-0xfc5cbfff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 69 (321 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001002d00001637sv00001002sd00001637bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #20 (PCI bridge)

22: PCI 400.6: 0403 Audio device
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: kjQT.upx_VEV2TkC
  Parent ID: JZZT.e+TNXSUNut3
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.6
  SysFS BusID: 0000:04:00.6
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "AMD Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x1022 "AMD"
  Device: pci 0x15e3 "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1043 "ASUSTeK Computer Inc."
  SubDevice: pci 0x1f11 
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xfc5c0000-0xfc5c7fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 70 (6351 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001022d000015E3sv00001043sd00001F11bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #20 (PCI bridge)

29: PCI 100.1: 0403 Audio device
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: NXNs.0CWzWHZhA0E
  Parent ID: mnDB.zF_92iXwYcA
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1
  SysFS BusID: 0000:01:00.1
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "nVidia Audio device"
  Vendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x2291 
  SubVendor: pci 0x1043 "ASUSTeK Computer Inc."
  SubDevice: pci 0x14fc 
  Revision: 0xa1
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xfc080000-0xfc083fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 67 (233 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000010DEd00002291sv00001043sd000014FCbc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #24 (PCI bridge)
```

```
$ lspci | grep Audio
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2291 (rev a1)
04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
04:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in Settings...Sound... and see which one is chosen.

Mine only works properly when I have the Line Out Family 17H  one chosen.

[image: family 17h sound]

I also have had some odd experience with the FireFox web browser & my sound when playing videos -- I would hear crackling popping & the sound level would be low.  When I would switch to a different browser it would work.

Oh, also, are you running Wayland windowing system?  Or area you running X11?
I've seen a number of problems with Wayland and when I switched away (to X11) on 22.04 I didn't have any problems after.

Checking Settings...About...
Windowing System

[image: x11 system about]

Here's how you can change it if you want to : [Use X11 instead of Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04).

Comment: I have the `Speakers - Family 17H` as an output device. I had a Wayland windowing system and I switched to X11 as you suggested, but it didn't help with sound problems (however it helped with others issues so thank you). Sound in web browsers is good, I only have this issue in VLC or other media players.