# Can't turn off Wacom Touch anymore

Tags: drivers, touchscreen, tablet, wacom

I've been using my Wacom Cintiq Companion 2 on my Desktop PC, which has Ubuntu 22.04 installed, for the past two years, and I've used a terminal command to disable the touchscreen function and do everything just with my pen.
Alas, this morning this tablet seems to not "register" anymore the command, and the touch function remains active.
When I type it in the terminal, I receive this output.

```
$ xsetwacom set "Wacom ISDv5 326 Finger touch" touch off
Wayland devices found but this tool is incompatible with Wayland. See 
https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Wayland
```

I receive the same output when I try to just check if the name of the tablet has changed in the ubuntu settings.

```
$ xsetwacom --list
Wayland devices found but this tool is incompatible with Wayland. See
https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Wayland
```

This never happened before and I don't know where to look at. Trying to draw with the tablet always perceiving the pressure of the side of my hand as a touch input is out of the question. So please, what can I do? Try to install the Linux Wacom project drivers instead of rolling with the default ones?

Comment: Workaround: Since it does not work with Wayland (according to the terminal output), use X.Org instead of Wayland. https://askubuntu.com/q/1410256/124466

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use X instead of wayland on 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04)