# X11 display server protocol configured

Tags: 22.04, xorg

I have installed a clean version of  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, updated everything then installed VMware Horizon 8 Client for Linux 64-bit.

When I launch the client I get the following error:

> the display server protocol you are using is not supported. recommend to log in with x11 display server protocol configured.

Can anyone point me to instructions on how to configure X11 display server protocol?

Comment: Does this help? [How do I use X instead of wayland on 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04)

Answer (score -1):

You need to edit the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` file to disable Wayland then restart.

Comment: Removing the pound sign on the line "#WaylandEnable=false" in that file did the trick for me, the error message is not showing anymore. Thanks.