# Problems with nvidia on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, 22.04, gpu

Trying to install Ubuntu for the first time as needed for a course but having difficulties getting it to use my GPU. With the xorg driver it never uses my GPU for anything and so I get lots of lag even just moving windows around. I have tried installing Nvidia drivers with multiple methods and occasionally it works but then stops working properly overnight. Complete noob when it comes to Linux so any advice would be appreciated.
(Using 3070ti and i5-12400f)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: how did you install drivers?

Comment: I have tried all methods on this page https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/#verification.  Aswell as using the Unix driver installation from Nvidias own site. Like I said they work fine even after multiple reboots but twice after waking up the next day I start having lots of issues again. Not sure how it can break overnight without me touching anything.

Comment: There is only one good method `ubuntu-drivers install`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)

Comment: I tried using that after a fresh install (and updating all packages) just now but I get al lot of errors in the terminal and Ubuntu drivers crashes.

Comment: I managed to get the command to work and install everything after editing a line in python3 but after reboot I'm now getting lots of issues such as being unable to do anything but open terminal, random 100cpu usage, refresh rate only set to 93hz (165hz monitor).

Comment: Is there anyway for me to force the nouveau xorg drivers that come with my Ubuntu install to detect and use my GPU as every Nvidia driver version I have tried installing I get issues with

Answer (score 0):

I am running the NVidia Geforce GTX 1660 and I've had some issues in the past while running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

1. Here is the driver that my system works really well with:

[image: 470 driver]

2. Remove wayland and run the X windowing system ([How do I use X instead of wayland on 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04?noredirect=1&lq=1))

You can check which windowing system you are running in your system settings:

[image: system settings windowing system]