# Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS cant detect my graphic tablet

Tags: drivers, 22.04, xinput, graphics-tablet

so just fyi, i dont understand linux that much, im still kinda learning, so sorry if i mess up something.

Anyways, i have a drawing tablet xp-pen star 03, and i tried connecting it to my computer. it works as a mouse, but i expected something, like scrolling using swiping, just like windows has it. i downloaded the drivers, and checked the settings. In the settings, it says that no tablet was detected so i checked other posts and i guess it has something supposted to do with xinput?
so heres the thing that it said

```
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:17                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:17              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:17              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet stylus:17                 id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet eraser:17                 id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet cursor:17                 id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:17                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

so if anyone have any idea how this works, or if the stuff that is on windows even works on linux, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try switching to the X.Org session? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi im not sure if i understood the page well, but i already had waylandEnabled set to false

Comment: Are you sure it works with this version of Ubuntu? How old is the tablet?

Comment: @David It should be compatible, it says that it works with Ubuntu 10.10 and above, and its like 3 years old.

Comment: The release date for that version 10.10 was 10 October 2010. So I would say the opposite  most likely wont work with a current version. That is very old hardware.

Comment: yea, but the tablet is from 2020, so i dont really think its that old