# ubuntu 23.04, no pulseaudio, only pipewire, ffmpeg, no audio when record desktop

Tags: sound, ffmpeg

On Ubuntu 23.04, there is only `pipewire`, no pulse audio.

When I use `ffmpeg` for record desktop, no sound is recording.

In case I use `hw:1`, it record one second of audio and then silence. Does `ffmpeg` support pipewire already?

```
  ffmpeg \
  -f alsa -i hw:1 \
  -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate $framerate -f x11grab -i :1 -c:v libx264 -qp 0 \
  -crf 40 \
  output.mp4
```

UPDATE:

I tried install Kazam. Kazam stucked when I stopped the recording, so I think it is similar issue.

Comment: Might be a Wayland issue. Switch to X https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04 and retry with Kazam.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Hi, I am already out of Wayland on X, because of correct work with touchscreen. Seems this issue is probably related to pipewire support. Any ideas? Did someone try record desktop with pipewire only?