# Onboard screenkeyboard does not work in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: onboard

Since I've upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, I can't use the onboard         screenkeyboard anymore. I really liked that keyboard, because it is compact, easy functionality (right click for characters etc.) etc... The onboard freezes now to one side of the screen, I can't type with it at all, other programs have strange behaviors.
Is there a solution to fix the onboard, so I can use it again? Or is there something similar? I now use the screen keyboard which is available in Ubuntu itself, but I don't like this one. It sometimes presses keys automatic, takes a lot of space at the bottom of the screen, no right click functionality etc...

Comment: Check if `/usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher` is running: `pgrep -af spi` . 
Onboard depends on python3. 
You can ask help from https://bugs.launchpad.net/onboard

Comment: How do I check? Can you give the exact command line?

Comment: `pgrep -af spi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It works for me in Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.2 LTS when using X**

[I switched from Wayland to X](https://askubuntu.com/q/1410256/124466).

See the picture, how to start the Settings/Preferences window from tray, and then untick 'Dock to screen edge'.

[image]

---

**Edit the configuration file to switch from Wayland to X:**

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

to uncomment [remove # from] the line containing

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

save the file (**<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>** and after that <kbd>y</kbd> ('yes') or another key for non-English and finally <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and reboot.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi , Thanks for editing the link :-)

Comment: Maybe this is the problem. I'm running Wayland :)

Comment: Try X and good luck @AnnekevanderWal :-)

Comment: I hope I don't crash my system :)

Comment: If you save a backup copy of the config file, it will be easy to restore but it is a small and straight-forward fix. I will edit the answer to add instructions.

Comment: thank you! I'll try, and come back when I managed it.

Comment: Ok, I'm back and I've managed it to switch to X.
I've also reinstalled onboard, and it works again! I'm so happy! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145925/discussion-between-sudodus-and-anneke-van-der-wal).

Comment: Since I switched to X, the pc is slower. Sometimes, when I turn off the pc, I get a FAILED warning.
You have any idea?

Comment: You can check some log files in the directory `/var/log`. (There are other people who know much better than I what to look for in the log files.) I think it is best to ask a new question focusing on this new problem. That way you have better chances for make the experts in that field interested. - You can also [install and] run the program `htop` and see which programs are using the CPU. And you can turn back to Wayland for a while and check what looks different in the logs and in `htop`.