# Firefox display glitches then freezes when resizing on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, firefox, snap, gui

I updated to Ubuntu 22.04 a few months ago on a MSI laptop half a year ago and have been having the same recurring display issue with Mozilla Firefox.

Sometimes when resizing the Mozilla window the window will glitch and start partially showing as a black square or, if shrinking, it cuts down the menus instead of resizing the content. It's hard to explain but last time I managed to take a [screen recording](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/13lrtob/firefox_display_glitches_and_freezes_when/) (upload to reddit post).

The program remains somewhat responsive (I can change tabs with keyboard shortcuts) but can't be minimized or restored to fullscreen, the only "fix" I've found is closing it by right-clicking the icon and opening the browser again. I'm not a tab hoarder so I don't think it's a memory issue.

I can't pinpoint what triggers the glitch, I have not been able to reproduce it at will.

I tried a clean install a while ago, as well as disabling all extensions, but the issue popped up again. Any ideas or pointers will be much appreciated, I've always used firefox and would rather not have to change browsers.

Sys info:

- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (64-bit)
- Windowing system: Wayland
- GNOME: 42.5

Firefox info:

- Mozilla Firefox snap for Ubuntu
- Version 113.0.1 (64-bit)
- canonical-002 - 1.0

Comment: Does your laptop has a touch screen? Otherwise, switch to the X.Org session. It is supposed to have less bugs. https://askubuntu.com/a/1413490/124466 Also check if using the apt version instead of the snap version helps https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466

Comment: @arch no, no touch screen, will try the apt and look into xorg. Any ideas on what could cause it?

Comment: Snap and wayland have a lot of bugs. If apt and X work, just go with it

Comment: I have the same bug!
Identical problem using snap/Wayland/Gnome 42.9/Ubuntu 22.04. It worked perfectly on Ubuntu 20.04 (also using Multi-Monitors Add On GNOME extension, which is no longer supported in GNOME 4), but upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 broke everything.

Comment: I can also confirm that this bug is *not* present in Ubuntu 22.04 on Xorg. So this is not snap-Firefox-, GNOME 4-, or Ubuntu 22.04-related. It seems to be yet another Wayland bug. Maybe they'll figure out Wayland eventually, but the current recommendation is just to always stick with Xorg, especially if you're multimonitoring.

Comment: This bug occurs when running Firefox on XWayland. You can change Firefox to run on Wayland natively to resolve this (and many other) issued. I provided a guide for Flatpak users here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1483129/180983