# Sound stuttering in virtual machine

Tags: sound, pipewire

In Ubuntu 23.04 and 22.10 installed in VMware 13 there is sound stuttering. Ubuntu 20.04 does not have this problem. In Fedora 38 I also had problems with sound. In fedora 38 I changed the file `~/.config/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua`. I set these values. This solved the problem.

```
["api.alsa.period-size"]   = 1024,
["api.alsa.headroom"]      = 8192,
```

But this doesn't help in Ubuntu 23.04. What can I try to fix the sound problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same stuttering / choppy sound issue. My config is VirtualBox on Windows10 with Ubuntu 23.04 as client. All 64bit and fully up-to-date. Nightmare to find some data which lead me into the right directions.

Although not fully tested yest I think you might find a solution here:
[How do I use X instead of wayland on 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04)

In other words Wayland is causing the issue. Disable it as suggested and reboot.