# night light; old macbook

Tags: nvidia, mac

Is my Macbook 5,2 (year 2009) (graphics Nvidia; nvac/nv96) incompatible with the "night light" function in 23.04?

I don't think any proprietary drivers are available for the Nvidia card.

I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu, so I don't know how to answer the question, "Are you using GNOME?". I installed Ubuntu from the Live USB and have not done anything that I'm aware of related to GNOME. In Setting>About, my GNOME version is listed as "Not Available".

Comment: Are you using GNOME?

Comment: Also, try switching to X.Org https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04

Comment: I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu, so I don't know how to answer the question, "Are you using GNOME?". I installed Ubuntu from the Live USB and have not done anything that I'm aware of related to GNOME. In Setting>About, my GNOME version is listed as "Not Available".

Comment: Can you run this in terminal: echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP

Should give you an output of your desktop environment.

Comment: The desktop is GNOME.