# How can I access my Ubuntu machine running X11/Xorg from Windows 10?

Tags: ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding

I have a laptop running Windows 10 (or Windows 11). I can `ssh` into my Ubuntu computer with `ssh cocomac@192.168.1.XYZ`, but I'd like to either (a) use a GUI app from Windows or (b) use the entire desktop from Windows. Ideally, I'd like to do this via X forwarding, rather than VNC or RDP. Note that I'm *not* using Wayland here.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with two machines. I'll have a recent (22H2) Windows 10 computer and a Ubuntu 23.04 machine. The Ubuntu machine will run stock Ubuntu desktop. I'll be using a minimal install of Ubuntu, but a full installation should work fine to. I further assume that your Ubuntu computer [has been configured to run Xorg, not Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/q/1410256/1438484). *This is not the default.*

---

On the Windows machine, download VcXsrv from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/files/vcxsrv/), and run the installer. At the time of writing, the file was called `vcxsrv-64.1.20.14.0.installer.exe`. The version will likely vary over time, though. In the VcXsrv installer, accept the defaults, they are fine.

On Ubuntu, run `sudo apt update && sudo apt install openssh-server`. Run `hostname -I` to find your IP address.
Let's pick an app to run remotely. I'll choose `/usr/bin/gnome-text-edit`. On the actual Ubuntu computer (i.e., not over SSH), run `/usr/bin/gnome-text-edit`. The text editor should open. Close it. We just needed to ensure it worked.

Let's try that from Windows, via SSH. In Windows, run `ssh -X username@[Ubuntu IP address here]`. That either gave an error like `(gnome-text-editor:2524): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:51:24.488: cannot open display:`. That wasn't what we wanted. If it opened the text editor, but on the Ubuntu computer, double-check that you're not using Wayland. On Windows, run XLaunch (it's an app, not a shell command). That is what was installed by the VcXsrv installer. Select `Multiple windows`, and a Display number of three (`3`). Select `Start no client`, and check `Disable access control`, and do Finish.

Find the IP address of your Windows computer by running `ipconfig` in the terminal (I'm using Powershell). My Windows IP is `192.168.1.141`. Now do

```shell
DISPLAY='192.168.1.141:3.0' /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor
```

in the SSH session. The app should launch on Windows. Note that `192.168.1.141` is the IP of your *Windows* computer, not your Ubuntu computer.

Done! You should be able to do the same thing with any GUI app. Note that this works on Xorg, not Wayland. Also note that I choose a display number of three somewhat randomly. Avoid using one that's already taken, so I picked three, but other numbers that aren't in use should work fine.

Comment: For me it was easier to use MobaXTerm on Windows 10 as it has a built-in X server, so after connecting via SSH I could just run xterm or whatever and it just worked. https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/