# Errors when running a swing application on Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: xorg, java

I'm trying to run a very simple "hello world" Java application with swing on my computer where I have installed Ubuntu 22.04.2.

I have installed Java SDK 17 and have JAVA_HOME set on my `~/.bashrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

I have tried to set the DISPLAY value with:

```
unset DISPLAY
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Does it work [when you use X instead of Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04)?