# autokey doesn't work in command line action

Tags: command-line, autokey

For some reason, autokey shortkey doesnt work on command line action for example, terminal or changing folder name.

Except that, every app works fine.
I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance in resolving this problem.

Here's the background information:
Ubuntu version: 22.04.2 LTS
AutoKey version: 0.96
CPU: Intel i5-1340
GPU: Intel Iris Xe graphics

Thank you

Comment: Note that Autokey works on Xorg. So if you use Wayland, the default on Ubuntu 22.04, it will only work if the program does not natively run on Wayland (i.e., on Xorg through xwayland).

Comment: Thank you so much!
I fixed it by following introduction chainging WaylandEnable
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so the question can be marked as solved.

Comment: Thank you for giving advise to use community.
I've just updated.

Answer (score 0):

by changing the Wayland option it works perfectly

[reference link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04)
You can enable the X using the terminal. Open the terminal and run the command:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

There you will find or commented

```
WaylandEnable=True
```

change it to

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

And restart the system