# Caps Lock Issue with Ubuntu 22.04 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, capslock

So I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 11 for the sake of making it my main Programming machine while windows being my Microsoft Office machine.

but I am encountering this weird caps lock delay issue like instead of "Hey" I type "HEy". I looked everywhere but all I could find were just scripts..

I am fairly new to Linux but I somehow managed to try them but they were of no fix, is there any solution that actually works?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) And provide us more details.

Comment: Are you using capslock to type capital letters instead of using Shift? Apparently this is a standard Linux issue from a long time ago, see https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1462333.html

Comment: [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1376903) is an official bug report, it still hasn't been fixed apparently. The linked question above has some steps that might fix it, but in general learning to use Shift instead of Capslock for quickly typing capital letters will avoid this issue

Comment: The XKB fix will only work if you are using Xorg as a display server, but the default in recent Ubuntu releases is Wayland. You can [switch to Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04) and try the steps linked above, which should fix things for you

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! @Esther, it's really sad & funny that they still haven't fixed this lol.

Comment: @ItzKenny as explained in the Arch Wiki link from the first question I linked, it's an intentional design choice meant to mimic typewriters. Capslock doesn't turn off until after the "up" keypress to turn it off, so if you type another letter before you pick up your hand from the capslock, it won't be off yet.