# Update to Ubuntu 22 always reverts to unscore start after a few reboots

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, xorg

So I have updated ubuntu 20 to ubuntu 22 and it is fine, then after a few reboots a few days later it reverts back to having to start it in tty mode. Then when I go "startx" it fails saying no screens found.
-It works when I go into recovery mode (select an old Kernel I think is what I am doing).
-In this mode it only shows on one monitor not a few.
I have tried:

```
sudo Xorg -configure
```

Anyways here is the log hopefully someone can help. I was going to upload my Xorg.0.log, but I assuming that now that I have booted in with the old kernel it overwrote it as it looks fine in the log now.

Before it was essentially saying:
drm report modesetting isn't supported
no screens found

Any help is appreciated. Really not liking this Ubuntu 22 LTS, 20 LTS I had less graphical problems.

Comment: Disabling Wayland is recommended for Nvidia: https://askubuntu.com/q/1410256/1004020