# xrandr --panning returns BadRRCrtc error (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: 22.04, xorg, display

I occassionay need to use panning to have a larger (virtual) desktop to move around on my Lenovo laptop. On my previous laptop I used xrandr for that.

```
xrandr --listactivemonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*XWAYLAND18 1920/310x1080/170+0+0  XWAYLAND18
```

I now tried the following, but got an error message:

```
xrandr --verbose --output XWAYLAND18 --panning 1920x1500

crtc 0:    1920x1080  59.96 +0+0 "XWAYLAND18"
X Error of failed request:  BadRRCrtc (invalid Crtc parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  29 (RRSetPanning)
  Crtc id in failed request: 0x561
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

This is the info from lspci:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 185, IOMMU group 2
    Memory at 603c000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

```
uname  -a
Linux mylapubu 6.5.0-15-generic #15~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jan 12 18:54:30 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

(There is no need for a multi-monitor setup and the screen works normally without any problems at 1920x1080)

Comment: xrandr is read-only on Wayland. Either use a Wayland tool or switch to X11: https://askubuntu.com/q/1410256/1004020